# How to get wishlist collection using customer id in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I am trying to get the wish list products in Magento 1.9, I am facing some problem. Based on customer id am fetching customer details, Unable to fetch the wishlist product collections.

```
$customer_id= 4;
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
            if($customer){
                $wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
                print_r($wishList);
                $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
                if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
                    $arrProductIds = array();
                    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
                        $product = $item->getProduct();
                        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if still not solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the customer ID is 1 and you want tot get the wishlsit items of the customer having the customer ID 1.

Please use the code like below:

```
<?php

class Stack_Wishlistitems_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $customerId = 4;
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        $wishlistItems = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                ->setWebsiteId($customer->getWebsiteId())
                ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());
        echo "<pre>";print_r($wishlistItems->getData());exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Iam having doubt in the wist collection, Can any one please help me to fix this. [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943694/how-to-add-pagination-for-wishlist-products-in-magento-1-9 ]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($customer->getId()){
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer,true);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    $arrProductIds = array();

    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```